# How can I hide a portion of annotation outside innerplotposition in mschart?

Tags: c#, annotations, mschart

In mschart, if I add line annotations and scoll chart, there is line annotation  outside innerplotposition.
I want to draw annotations and image  only in innerplotposition area.
How can I hide a portion of annotation outside innerplotposition?

my reference  [How to let user create Annotations on MSChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912060/how-to-let-user-create-annotations-on-mschart/39913263#39913263)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEfwG.png)

Comment: It is (almost) straightforward: `ClipToChartArea` will be enough. The name is misleading, as, as you have noticed, it is really about the `InnerPlotPosition` -  I have updated the answer with two lines. See there!

Comment: TaW , Thank you.